# JSON Array from PHP encode in undefined in main JS file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have today a very strange problem with JS array. First, I am encoding JSON array in php and echo an array:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var odpowiedzi = []; var odpowiedzi = '.json_encode($_SESSION['odpowiedzi']).'; alert(odpowiedzi);</script>';
```

What is interesting, I see here that alert with good data of my array but in 2nd JS file I am trying to see it again:

```
alert(odpowiedzi[0]);
```

And only thing I get is critical JS error of undefined:

```
VM5244:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

What is the problem? For test I made same thing with normal int variable and it is working! Please for help.

Comment: And what happens if you remove `[0]` from the second alert? Are you sure the JSON has an array as the first value, you did redefine the variable by declaring it twice.

Comment: Where is your second JS file included?

Comment: what is the output of `alert(odpowiedzi);` ? BTW your first instruction is useless `var odpowiedzi = [];`

Comment: @adeneo After first alert I am getting normal alert in browser like "value1,value2,value3"

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It is declared in first line after that php:
?> //here php is ending
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/funkcjesprawdzian2.js"></script>

Comment: @oliv37 look what I said to adeneo

Comment: do you load your second js file after the echo instruction ?

Comment: maybe you could try with `window.odpowiedzi =` rather than `var odpowiedzi  =` then you can alert with `alert(window.odpowiedzi)`

Comment: Thanks, it works with window. But in which way? I can't understand why only that way is working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your second JS file is getting loaded first. You can simply add console.log() commands and log the time when they get called to see if there's an issue with the order of your scripts getting loaded as such;

```
console.log('nth block execute time: ' + new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: No, that 2nd JS file is loading after that php... And my  test with normal int variable is proofing that sentence ;)